# If stationary points and minima are equivalent, then is the function convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, maxima-minima

Let $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function for which a minimum exists. If $f$ is convex, then

$$\{x \in \mathbb R^n : \nabla f(x) = 0\} = \{x \in \mathbb R^n : f(x) \leq f(y), \; \forall y \in \mathbb R^n\}.$$

However, is the converse statement true? That is, if the above equation holds (and the two sets are non-empty), then is $f$ necessarily convex? Furthermore, would compactness of these sets be relevant?

Comment: Take $n=1$ and $f(x)=-e^x$. The sets in your question are equal because both are empty.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you for the observation. I edited the question.

Comment: To get the sets nonempty, try letting (still with $n=1$) $f(x)=x^2-1$ for $x\leq1$ and $f(x)=2\ln x$ for $x\geq 1$. (I hope I did the arithmetic right so that the values and derivatives match up at $x=1$ which makes $f$ differentiable. With more work, you could make an infinitely differentiable $f$ with the same general shape.) Both sets in your question are $\{0\}$, so they're equal, nonempty, and compact. But $f$ isn't convex to the right of $x=1$.

Comment: This question reminds me of a [paper by Saint Raymond](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00009-012-0226-0). He shows that that in a general Banach space $X$, a lower-semicontinuous function $f$ is convex if, given any $l \in X^*$, the function $f + l$ achieves its minimum on a non-empty, convex set.

Comment: The property you are looking for is invexity, see Theorem 1 of [this paper](http://benisrael.net/INVEXITY.pdf)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the converse is not correct. Here is a counterexample:

[image: nonconvex counter-example]

This function is smooth, nonconvex, yet it has a unique global minimiser which satisfies Fermat's condition.

By the way, a convex function does not necessarily satisfy the condition you mentioned - you need additional conditions. Take for example $f(x) = e^x$.

If a (convex or nonconvex) function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is lower semicontinuous and level bounded, then $\inf f$ is finite and its set of minimisers is nonempty and compact. A function $f$ is said to be level bounded if its level sets (the sets $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: f(x) \leq a\}$) are bounded for every $a\in \mathbb{R}$ (they might be empty for some $a$).

**Update:** Another counter-example is the following function

$$
f(x) = \frac{x}{e^{-2x} + 1}
$$

Its graph looks a little like the one above.